# Isolate power variable

Tags: calculus

I need to isolate `m` from this [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7ENV.png):

$$e=\frac{c t}{1-(1+t)^{-m}}$$

I can pass the dividend to the left (multiplying e) and after pass e as a dividend in the division. But my problem is that I don't know how to isolate powers like m.

PD: sorry for my English, and I can't show the image directly

Comment: Just using logarithms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rearranging, you will obtain a relation like

$$a^m=b.$$

This is solved by taking the logarithms of the members,

$$\log a^m=m\log a=\log b$$ then

$$m=\frac{\log b}{\log a}.$$

By a property of the logarithms, you can use any base.

Answer (score 0):

Fill in details and give justifications in the following:

$$e=\frac{c t}{1-(1+t)^{-m}}\implies1-(1+t)^{-m}=\frac{ct}e\implies(1+t)^{-m}=1-\frac{ct}e=\frac{e-ct}e\implies$$

$$(1+t)^m=\frac e{e-ct}\stackrel{\text{apply in both sides}\log}\implies m\log(1+t)=\log\frac e{e-ct}\implies\ldots\;\text{etc.}$$

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it appears you can get to $1-(1+t)^{-m}=\frac{ct}{e}$ so I shall go from there.

$\begin{align*}
&Rearranging\ gives\\
&(1+t)^{-m}=1-\frac{ct}{e}\\
&Taking\ logs\ of\ both\ sides\ gives\\
&-mLn(1+t)=Ln(1-\frac{ct}{e})=Ln(\frac{e}{ct})\\
&Dividing\ through\ by\ Ln(1+t)\ gives\\
&-m=\frac{Ln(\frac{e}{ct})}{Ln(1+t)}\\
&Using\ log\ rule,\ \frac{Log(a)}{Log(b)}=Log_{a}(b),\ gives\\
&m=-Log_{1+t}(\frac{e}{ct})
\end{align*}$